# Fix for defects in OneNote API returned URLs?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

It appears the OneNote API returns defective URLs to particular requests:

1) When fetching content from a shared notebook using the `GET-RecentNotebooks` API to first fetch the shared notebook, then using the `POST-GetNotebookFromWebUrl` API to get the required sections URL, a defective URL is returned, in the form `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/,<ID>/onenote/notebooks/<ID>/sections`. The deficiency is that a segment is missing, before the comma after the `/sites/` segment, which should contain the URL for the SharePoint site itself.

2) In the returned content itself, resource endpoints have an incorrect segment: the segment following `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/`) is incorrectly rendered as `siteCollections` instead of `sites`.

My questions: Can these defects be corrected in the OneNote API itself? Failing this, what is the best way for a developer to handle these defects?

Comment: My question received an initial response from @Manjusha (Software Engineer at Microsoft), saying this issue would be looked into and reported back. However, that comment has been deleted and there's been no response in the last 3 months. It'd be good to know whether it's still being investigated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We dealt with the first defect (a missing segment for the SharePoint site itself) by extracting the missing URL from the `webURL` and inserting it into the URL used to fetch content from a shared notebook (via the API `GET` operation).

However, it now (11 March 2021) appears that Microsoft's OneNote API developers have remedied this defect themselves, with the result that our own remedy now results in a duplicated segment in the `GET` request URL e.g. `oursite-my.sharepoint.comoursite-my.sharepoint.com`.

The remarkable thing is that this duplicated segment causes no problem to the API GET operation (verified in the Graph Explorer)! So we can only assume that the OneNote API developers have provided for our fix and strip out the duplicated segment!

It'd be nice to have a comment on this by the OneNote API developers.